# ST_Union 'MIN' on rasters with result raster having DN values as raster table column value

Tags: postgis, raster, sql

I am new to working with rasters in PostGIS. Although I have spent couple of days trying to find solution for my problem, I couldn't seem to crack it without some help.

Here's my problem:
I have multiple overlapping rasters in a PostGIS table (about 500 records) with each raster size about 1200x1000 (30m res.) but varies since data is dumped from different sources. The table looks as follows:

```
-- Table "coverage_rast"

   id   |   rast
(bigint)| (raster)
--------------
   5489 | "02301ff..."
   5489 | "238000f..."
   5489 | "02301ff..."
   1234 | "238000f..."
   1234 | "02301ff..."
   4567 | "238000f..."
   4567 | "238000f..."
```

Each raster record represents a coverage with some DN values(ranging 0-100). When I perform `CREATE TABLE sometable as SELECT ST_UNION(rast,1,'MIN') from coverage_rast;` gives me resultant raster with minimum values as DN values at each grid cell and takes about 2 minutes of query time. Instead I want that the resultant raster should be such that the DN value at each grid cell should represent "id" of the raster which has minimum value at that location.

I tried using `SELECT val,id FROM (SELECT ST_Value(rast, 1, geom) val,id FROM coverage_rast,(SELECT st_setsrid(ST_MakePoint(-80.85495, 35.21887),4326) geom)tbl
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, geom)) as t1 ORDER BY val LIMIT 1` which gets the id and the minimum DN value at given location. Was thinking of extending this by creating a uniform grid of points spaced 30m apart and passing geom column and then creating a raster out of it, but this would be pretty slow and sloppy.

I am hoping to find a solution which can extend `st_union` to assign `id` value as DN of raster where existing DN value is minimum of all the overlapping rasters.

Comment: Combine ID and DN values into a single 32-bit value, then use [ST_MapAlgebra](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MapAlgebra.html) (which runs only on a single band).

Comment: @CL. following your comment I tried to combine ID and DN values by using `create table sometable as select ST_MapAlgebra(rast, 1, NULL, '[rast]*"id"') from coverage_rast`  but it gives `column "id" not found` error. I understand that column names are not permitted in MapAlgebra expression. I looked into [st_reclass](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Reclass.html) but it seems that `reclassexpr` also does not allow column names. So is there some other way to do this?

Comment: That's a complex case. You will need to develop your own ST_UnionID() aggregate function using ST_MapAlgebra() as the state function, a mix of raster value and ID as the state value and your own callback function returning the desired mix of those values (MIN or MAX).

Comment: The combination step would have to be done by hand (outside of PostGIS, or by handling individual pixels). It might be a better idea to not use PG at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [CL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/10588/cl)'s comments I combined the ID and DN values using psycopg2 such that e.g id=5489 and DN=144.5601 then the DN of new raster becomes 144564.5489. So I take float value with 2 decimal precision and in units place I keep the number of digits in the id(since id could be 4 or more digits long), and in the decimal places I keep the id value. So when I run ST_Union on the new raster I would get the ID also embedded in the DN. Then I run mapalgebra to use only the ID values and construct a new raster. Following is how I did it:

```
import psycopg2

tbl = "coverage_rast"
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname="+dbname+" port="+port+" host="+host+" password="+password+" user="+user)
cur = conn.cursor()

def create_ID_DN_combo(tbl,conn,cur):
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE "+tbl+" ADD COLUMN no_digits integer; update "+tbl+" set no_digits = (floor(log(id))+1);")
    conn.commit()     
    cur.execute("Select id,no_digits from "+tbl+";")   # no_digits is no. of digits in id
    cols = cur.fetchall()
    for i in range(len(cols)):
        cur.execute("update "+tbl+" set rast = st_mapalgebra(rast,1,'64BF','(floor([rast]*100)*10)+"+str(cols[i][1])+"+"+str(cols[i][0]/(10**len(str(cols[i][0]))))+"') where id="+str(cols[i][0])+";")
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("create table combo_tbl as select st_union(rast,1,'MIN')rast from "+tbl+";")
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("update combo_tbl set rast = st_mapalgebra(rast,1,'32BUI','round(([rast]-floor([rast]))*(10^(((floor([rast])/10)-floor(floor([rast])/10))*10)))');")
    conn.commit()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```